# Python Multiprocessing Process.start() wait for process to be started

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, multiprocessing

I have some testcases where I start a webserver process and then
run some URL tests to check if every function runs fine.

The server process start-up time is depending on the system where it is executed. It's a matter of seconds and I work with a time.sleep(5) for now.
But honestly I'm not a huge fan of sleep() since it might work for my systems but what if the test runs on a system where server needs 6 secs to start ... (so it's never really safe to go that way..)
Tests will fail for no reason at all.

So the question is: is there a nice way to check if the process really started.

I use the python multiprocessing module
Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import testapp.server
import requests
import testapp.config as cfg
import time
p = Process(target=testapp.server.main)
p.start()
time.sleep(5)
testurl=cfg.server_settings["protocol"] + cfg.server_settings["host"] + ":" +str(cfg.server_settings["port"]) + "/test/12"  

r = requests.get(testurl)
p.terminate()
assert int(r.text)==12
```

So it would be nice to avoid the sleep() and really check when the process started ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `is_alive` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive)) but that would almost always return True after you initiated `start()` on the process. If you want to make sure the process is already doing something important, there's no getting around the `time.sleep` (at least from this end, look at the last paragraph for another idea)

In any case, you could implement `is_alive` like this:

```
p = Process(target=testapp.server.main)
p.start()
while not p.is_alive():
    time.sleep(0.1)
do_something_once_alive()
```

As you can see we still need to "sleep" and check again (just 0.1 seconds), but it will probably be much less than 5 seconds until `is_alive` returns `True`.

If both `is_alive` and `time.sleep` aren't accurate enough for you to know if the process really does something specific yet, and if you're controlling the other program as well, you should have it raise another kind of flag so you know you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Did not know is_alive. But will it then not return immediately after the first sleep(0.1) when you say that: "but that would almost always return True after you initiated start() on the process"

Comment: Just tested it... it returns true immediately. not even entering the while loop...

Comment: @klaas In 99% of cases you're right. I don't know what the exceptions are. My suggestion is what I said at the end, have the other process raise some other flag and check for it. For example with a queue: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating your process with a [connection object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#connection-objects) as argument (other synchronization primitives may work) and use the `send()` method within your child process to notify your parent process that business can go on. Use the `recv()` method on the parent end of the connection object.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(conn):
    conn.send(0)  # argument object must be pickable
    # your worker is ready to do work and just signaled it to the parent

out_conn, in_conn = mp.Pipe()
process = mp.Process(target=worker,
                     args=(out_conn,))
process.start()
in_conn.recv()  # Will block until something is received
# worker in child process signaled it is ready. Business can go on
```