stuck with multithreading
i am reading multiple hdf5 files and those hdf5 file will be having datasets in heirarchy , i am fetching data from these hdf5 files , i am using multi threading inside hdf5 file to increase reading speed, also tell how can i make this fast, do i need to change my structure or reading way, i amm using python 2.7 and django 1.8:
present is :
their are multiple client_id.hdf5 , inside it multiple ship_ids -> report_types-> time_stamp-> in that data for that time
i did this , it is only printing till Data fetched. Starting multiprocessing...
('Processing client:', 112):
import h5py
import os
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
from vast import models
import dateutil.parser

from_date = dateutil.parser.parse('2023-06-01')
to_date = dateutil.parser.parse('2024-04-30')
boss_dir = '/home/bwit-laptop3/boss'
new_structure_dir = os.path.join(boss_dir, 'Data/new_mirror_data_for_fetching')

def fetch_and_save_data():
    data_dict = {}
    mirrors_info = models.mirrorv2_info.objects.filter(report_date__gte=from_date, report_date__lt=to_date, client_id=112)
    for mirror_info in mirrors_info:
        ship_id = mirror_info.ship_id
        report_date = mirror_info.report_date
        client_id = mirror_info.client_id
        report_type = mirror_info.report_type
        client_dict = data_dict.setdefault(client_id, {})
        ship_dict = client_dict.setdefault(ship_id, {})
        report_type_dict = ship_dict.setdefault(report_type, {})
        date_string = report_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        report_type_dict.setdefault(date_string, [])

    print("Data fetched. Starting multiprocessing...")
    for client_id, ships in data_dict.items():
        print("Processing client:", client_id)
        client_file_path = os.path.join(new_structure_dir, str(client_id) + ".hdf5")
        if not os.path.exists(client_file_path):
            continue
        with h5py.File(client_file_path, 'r') as client_file:
            queue = Queue()
            for ship_id, report_types in ships.items():
                queue.put((ship_id, report_types))
            threads = []
            for _ in range(4):  # Create 4 threads
                thread = Thread(target=process_ships, args=(client_file, queue))
                thread.start()
                threads.append(thread)
            for thread in threads:
                thread.join()

    file_path = os.path.join(boss_dir, 'data_fetch_new_way.json')
    directory = os.path.dirname(file_path)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data_dict, f)

    print("Data successfully saved to", file_path)

def process_ships(client_file, queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        ship_id, report_types = queue.get()
        read_ship_data(client_file, ship_id, report_types)
        queue.task_done()

def read_ship_data(client_file, ship_id, report_types):
    try:
        ship_id_str = str(ship_id)
        if ship_id_str not in client_file:
            print("Ship ID not found:", ship_id_str)
            return

        ship_group = client_file[ship_id_str]
        
        for report_type, dates in report_types.items():
            if report_type == "sof":
                report_type = report_type.upper()
            elif report_type.lower() in ["bunkering", "delay"]:
                report_type = report_type.capitalize()

            if report_type not in ship_group:
                print("Report type not found:", report_type, "for ship ID", ship_id_str)
                continue
            
            report_group = ship_group[report_type]
            
            for date_time, data_list in dates.items():
                timestamp = str(int(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())))
                if timestamp in report_group:
                    data = report_group[timestamp][0]
                    data_list.append(json.loads(data))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error processing ship data:", e)

start_time = time.time()
fetch_and_save_data()
time_taken = time.time() - start_time
print("The time taken is:", time_taken)


Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929895/python-multiprocessing-process-start-wait-for-process-to-be-started) solve your problem?

i dont think so , check now i changed my approach but still the output is exactly same ,should i also use is_alive approach ?? but where? can you guide please if you know

Python 2.7? Are you serious? What is vast?

yeah well it is what it is , and  vast is a folder that contains a models file with all modals

Instead of using is_Alive approach to make it robust and fast you can rewrite with futures
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=settings.WORKER_THREADS) as executor:
       future = executor.submit(client_file, queue)
       future_to_row[future] = row
for future in as_completed(future_to_row):
            future.result()


Create a queue and send values other than None to be processed.
You can effectively create your own thread pool by constructing a number of threads (let's call it NTHREADS) and maintain them in a list.
When a thread consumes None from the queue that is seen as an indication that the thread should stop processing.
Something like this:
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread, Lock

NTHREADS = 4

def pthread(q, k):
    # use a blocking get()
    while (value := q.get()) is not None:
        # acquire exclusive access to stdout
        with k:
            print(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    k = Lock()
    # create a "pool" of NTHREADS threads
    threads = [Thread(target=pthread, args=(q, k)) for _ in range(NTHREADS)]
    # start the threads
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    # put some values on the queue
    for x in range(10):
        q.put(x)
    # send None NTHREADS times to the queue
    # when a thread consumes None from the queue, it terminates
    for _ in range(NTHREADS):
        q.put(None)
    # wait for the threads to terminate
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

Possible output:
0
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1

